# Hadoop-2.6.0 build fails

Tags: visual-studio-2010, maven, hadoop, ant, hadoop2

Hadoop 2.6.0 build fails in windows. But Hadoop-2.5.0 built successfully. I am building the source using visual studio 2010 command prompt.

**Build Failure**

```
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Common ............................... SUCCESS [03:18 min]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop NFS .................................. SUCCESS [ 15.649 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop KMS .................................. SUCCESS [ 29.325 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Common Project ....................... SUCCESS [  0.031 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS ................................. FAILURE [ 31.917 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HttpFS ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS BookKeeper Journal .............. SKIPPED
```

**Error**

```
 [exec] (Link target) ->
 [exec]   jni_helper.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_JNI_CreateJavaVM referenced in function getGlobalJNIEnv [K:\Hadoop-2.6.0\hadoop-2.6.0-src\hadoop-hdfs-project\hadoop-hdfs\target\native\hdfs.vcxproj]
 [exec]   jni_helper.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs referenced in function getGlobalJNIEnv [K:Hadoop-2.6.0\hadoop-2.6.0-src\hadoop-hdfs-project\hadoop-hdfs\target\native\hdfs.vcxproj]
```

**Exception**

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run
(make) on project hadoop-hdfs: An Ant BuildException has occured: exec returned: 1
[ERROR] around Ant part ...<exec dir="K:\Hadoop-2.6.0\hadoop-2.6.0-src\hadoop
hdfs-project\hadoop-hdfs\target/native" executable="msbuild" failonerror="true">... @
8:140 in K:\Hadoop-2.6.0\hadoop-2.6.0-src\hadoop-hdfs-project\hadoop-hdfs\targe
\antrun\build-main.xml
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got a solution for the problem. My answer may help to someone.

I have installed 64 bit windows 8 and java jdk 32 bit. That's the problem when compiling hadoop hdfs native source.

I just installed java jdk 64 bit and the problem is resolved.

Comment: Hi Kumar, I was trying to build hadoop 2.5.0 for windows7, note that I dont have visual studio rather I do have windows SDK7.1. But couldnt complete the build got the below error.

Comment: Error: Build FAILED.

"C:\Hadoop_Source\hadoop-2.5.0-src\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\winutils.sln" (default target) (1) ->
(libwinutils target) -> 
  C:\Hadoop_Source\hadoop-2.5.0-src\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\winutils.sln : error MSB3411: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe". If the component is not installed, either 1) install the Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows Server 2008 and .NET Framework 3.5, or 2) install Microsoft Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: @Murugesh Check hadoop-2.6.0-src\building.txt file. They have given how to build using Windows SDK7.1.

Comment: Thanks Kumar, For 2.5.0 also I did follow the same.

Comment: You got the solution or still facing the same error?

Comment: Some files are missing to build the c++ file it seems. Better you can install visual studio 2010 or google it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you build hadoop on Linux evn.And then you can copy the dest files to windows.
I have built hadoop2.2 .here is the [download link 64bit](https://www.hightail.com/download/UlRTRm8zcHZqV0RLd01UQw)

Comment: from Hadoop 2.3.0 has native support for windows. If i build in linux, It will not work in Windows environment. In the Building.txt, they gave instruction how to build it in windows.

Comment: Did you have apache-maven env on windows?

Comment: Yes i have. As i told, I have build hadoop 2.5.0, 2.5.1, 2.5.2 in windows successfully. But 2.6.0 having this problem.

Comment: I am so sorry I have no idea anymore.Maybe you should email to the hadoop group.